# With cypress, control key pressed but keyup not trigerred after click event

Tags: cypress

I have this selection of multiple cells in a table while the control key must be pressed in order to select all the clicked cells:

```
cy.get("[data-cy=cell-1],[data-cy=cell-5],[data-cy=cell-32]")
  .click({ multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})
```

It works well, I see the multiple selection since selected cells have a different background color. I coded the page so when the window:keyup event on the control key happens, a dialog opens to edit the cells content. This works very well on dev, but with cypress, the `.click({ multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})` doesn't trigger my dialog, and if I had a manual `.type({ctrl})` after, it triggers the dialog but the multiple selection is lost

```
cy.get("[data-cy=cell-1],[data-cy=cell-5],[data-cy=cell-32]")
  .click({ multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})
cy.get("#my-table-container").type("{ctrl}")
```

It acts like for my first `click({multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})` the control key is down but never released. Do you know how could I use the click multiple and control but triggering the keyup at the end?

**UPDATE: @HostListener setup**
I am on Angular 12, here is exactly how I setup the key event with the @HostListener (I also listen the escape key to clear the cell selection):

```
@HostListener("window:keyup", ["$event"])
handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch(event.key){
      case "Escape": this.clearSelection(); break;
      case "Control":this.openEditDialog(); break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Cypress don't react as intended with the HostListener setup with `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode` (which is deprecated). I adapted in my component the @HostListener to use `event.keyCode === 17` and it worked.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the other way using `.trigger('keyup', { key: 'Control' })` and use your original @HostListener code.

Comment: I tried with both but it worked only with the keyCode, I'll try to update cypress.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `window:keyup` event, you could try to trigger that event, presume it's firing on the ctrl key (code 17).

```js
cy.get("[data-cy=cell-1],[data-cy=cell-5],[data-cy=cell-32]")
  .click({ multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})
cy.get("#my-table-container").trigger('keyup', { keyCode: 17 })
```

Also a keydown/keyup combo might work better (try with or without the `ctrlKey` modifier on `.click()`)

```js
cy.get('#my-table-container').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 17 })
cy.get('[data-cy=cell-1]').click({ctrlKey: true})
cy.get('[data-cy=cell-5]').click({ctrlKey: true})
cy.get('[data-cy=cell-32]').click({ctrlKey: true})
cy.get('#my-table-container').trigger('keyup', { keyCode: 17 })
```

Lastly, the target of the `.trigger()` may need to be something other than `#my-table-container`, depending on the way `addEventListener()` is invoked. Would need to see more of the HTML and source to be sure.

---

**Angular @HostListener**

If you have an event listener set by the @HostListener decorator as follows

```js
@HostListener("window:keyup", ["$event"])
onKeyup(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('keyup', event)
}
```

when you look a the console.log, the event has the path property `path: (4) [body, html, document, Window]` which means you can trigger it on `<body>`.

To check, the following test passes

```js
it('triggers keyup set by @HostListener on window', () => {
  let ev;
  cy.visit('http://localhost:4200').then(win => {
    cy.stub(win.console, 'log', (eventName, event) => {
      ev = event
    }).as('consoleLog')
  })

  cy.get('body').trigger('keyup', {keyCode:17})

  cy.get('@consoleLog')
    .should(() => {
      expect(ev.type).to.equal('keyup')
      expect(ev.keyCode).to.equal(17)
    })
})
```

So to trigger the dialog

```js
cy.get("[data-cy=cell-1],[data-cy=cell-5],[data-cy=cell-32]")
  .click({ multiple: true, ctrlKey: true})
cy.get('body')
  .focus()
  .trigger('keyup', { keyCode: 17 })
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it didn't worked as it is (I randomly put the cy.get("my-table-container") on the html table tag since the control key event is listened on the window level. About the event listener implementation, it's an Angular project, I implemented it with @HostListener("window:keyup", ["$event"])` and testing `event.key === "Control"`. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: To be more precised, when I say it didn't work, actually the multiple cell selection still works, but then the dialog opening is not done.

Comment: `<body>` should do it, please see POC above.

Comment: I tried with body but still the same behavior, mutliple selection works but then open dialog is not triggered. When I console.log the event as you did, I don't have exactly the same path, I get `path: (4) [body.mat-typography, html, document, Window]`, so I also tried with cy.get('body.mat-typography').

Comment: Also a strange thing, we can use the tested frame again when the test is completed, I removed all we tried previously so there is no failure, so if my test end with the multiple selection and after that I simply press the control key, the open dialog opens (I don't even have to click on the tested frame to focus on it or what so ever)

Comment: There must be some difference between the @HostListener I have and yours. For one thing you mention `event.key === "Control"` but my event doesn't have a key property.

Comment: I update my post to show how I used the @hostlistener

Comment: I remember I used event.key instead of event.keyCode because my IDE tells me event.key is deprecated. I tried your solution with the cy.get("body") and in my code using event.keyCode instead of event.key, it works like a charm! BUT, I am a little bit disapointed to use the deprecated event.key just for the tests... Do you know how I could make cypress understand event.key?